# Can I use Python to run a piece of VBA code without my macro being saved in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Im working on automating some spreadsheets and when using OpenPyXl to comment in a spreadsheet it does not size the comments correctly.

I added a macro to the spreadsheet that autosizes the comments, however I have been told the spreadsheet has to be kept as I was given it and the macro cannot be added.

Can I add this macro by implementing it in my python code somehow? or calling a VBA script?

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub AutoFitCommentBox()
    Set myRange = Application.Selection
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select one Range that contain comment boxes:", "AutoFitCommentBox", myRange.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each oneCell In myRange
        If Not oneCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            oneCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could add the code to another workbook project and open that workbook programmatically...? If it can be implemented to your python code that would probably be better but I don't know python or if that's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code compiles and runs OK - If you are interested in improving the `UserForm` code you might find [this article about UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) useful.

This solution will make use of a `UserForm` with a `ComboBox` and `CommandButton` on it - all of which have their default names.

*You will need to open the Excel workbook you save this code to (and remember to save in macro enabled format). You can open the workbook with additional code which you can add if you desire.*

When the form loads, the `ComboBox` will populate a list of all open Excel Workbook names. **Note:** I haven't tested with this code, but if memory serves me correctly, it won't find workbooks that are open in a separate instance of Excel - this means your workbook *may* not appear in the list.

When the user makes their selection, the form hides and then calls your code you wrote with the addition of passing on the `Workbook name` selected in the userform. With this your code will specifically target the named workbook without the code being written in it.

### In the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

### In the `UserForm1` code module:

```
Option Explicit
___________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ComboBoxSelection As String
ComboBoxSelection = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Me.Hide

AutoFitCommentBox (ComboBoxSelection)

End Sub
___________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim WorkbookNameArray As Variant
Dim ArrayElementCounter As Long

WorkbookNameArray = FindOpenWorkbooks

For ArrayElementCounter = LBound(WorkbookNameArray) To UBound(WorkbookNameArray)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem WorkbookNameArray(ArrayElementCounter)
Next ArrayElementCounter
End Sub
```

### In the `Module1` code module:

```
Public Sub AutoFitCommentBox(ByVal TargetWorkbookName As String)
    Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks(TargetWorkbookName)

    With TargetWorkbook
        Set myRange = Application.Selection
        Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select one Range that contain comment boxes:", "AutoFitCommentBox", myRange.Address, Type:=8)

        Dim oneCell As Variant
        For Each oneCell In myRange
            If Not oneCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                oneCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
_________________________________________________________________________________

Public Function FindOpenWorkbooks() As Variant

Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Dim WorkbookArray As Variant
Dim ArrayElementCounter As Long

ReDim WorkbookArray(1 To Application.Workbooks.Count)
i = LBound(WorkbookArray)

For Each myWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
    WorkbookArray(i) = myWorkbook.Name
    i = i + 1
Next myWorkbook

FindOpenWorkbooks = WorkbookArray

End Function
```

For reference, here is a screenshot of the `UserForm` I created:

[image: Screenshot of userform]